# iOS13 application openUrl? (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios13

How do you import files to your app on ios13?

Previously I could download a txt file in Safari and chose Copy to (app) and I would catch this in the app delegate open Url delegate. Doesn't work anymore.

The Copy To is still there in Safari, but it just dismissed Safari and nothing happens.

-- Edit:

Sorry, I was a bit unclear.
Previously, when downloading a file through another app (like Safari), the user could select to open this file in my app by tapping "Copy To (app)".

I would then catch this copy request through the appdelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    [...]
}
```

This delegate is not called in iOS13, only iOS12 and below.

I have tried finding a way to catch the "Copy to" request from other apps to no avail. There seems to be a new way of handling these things through a SceneDelegate?

Comment: You mean you want to **download** a file? No need for Safari, just use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl?language=objc).

Comment: Please see my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: In the scene delegate implement `windowScene:openURL:...`

Comment: Another option is to create an [Action Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html).

Comment: Alright thanks! I'm having serious trouble implementing the scene delegate and hooking it up. Some rudimentary thing here I'm not getting. So the scenedelegate is a dedicated class? Where do I hook it up?

Comment: I created a new project and saw how it was setup there. The SceneDelegate does not have any windowScene:openURL though?

Answer (score 2):

In projects having `SceneDelegate.swift` file, should implement `scene:openURLContext` method.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    print(#function)
    print(URLContexts)
}
```

Output:

```
scene(_:openURLContexts:)

[
 <UIOpenURLContext: 0x282fbca20;
 URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A644621B-BD6C-443B-A9D1-A212EA59EE2E/Documents/Inbox/file.pdf;
 options: <UISceneOpenURLOptions: 0x2823112c0;
 sourceApp: (null); 
 annotation: (null); 
 openInPlace: NO>>
]
```

Reference: [Migration from AppDelegate to SceneDelegate](https://www.vtourraine.net/blog/2019/wwdc-2019-multiple-windows-ipad)

Answer (score 2):

Version for Objective C.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    [[CommonController sharedInstance] handleExternalUrl: url];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
                    openURL:(NSURL *)url
                    options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
{
    NSLog(@"application openURL: %@", url);
    return [[CommonController sharedInstance] handleExternalUrl: url];
}

- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){   
    NSSet *c = connectionOptions.URLContexts;
    if(c && [c count] > 0)
    {
        NSURL *url = ((UIOpenURLContext*)[[c allObjects] firstObject]).URL;
        [[CommonController sharedInstance] handleExternalUrl: url];
    }
}

- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene openURLContexts:(nonnull NSSet<UIOpenURLContext *> *)URLContexts
API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
    NSURL *url = [[URLContexts allObjects] firstObject].URL;
    [[CommonController sharedInstance] handleExternalUrl: url];
}
```